# back button in lwuit with blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, lwuit, lwuit-button, lwuit-command

I developed an mobile application using LWUIT and it works fine in devices with J2ME.
I want to run the same application in Blackberry also.
I saw some samples about LWUIT on Blackberry but none of them answered me.

How can I handle the back button on the device to make back movements?
What I mean is that, when I press the back button on the device, I want the application move to the previous screen.

I used regular buttons to handle back movements just for now, but when we think of user side, it is not so friendly.

I dont want to use commands like I did in j2ME app., because it seems not so nice.

Is there anyone who can solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a particular back command to the form. For example,

```
Command backCmd = new Command("Back"){

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
   previousForm.show();
  }
};

currentForm.setBackCommand(backCmd);
```

Comment: thanks for answer,I did the same just for now, but this is not what I mean, I think I couldn't explain the problem. The problem is handling the button on the device, not commands in application. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Look on [`button.getCommand()`](http://lwuit.java.net/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/Button.html#getCommand()). I didn't check this before. So Just test it and let me.

Comment: actually, previously, same as back button, my trackball and delete buttons has been also not worked, but I was able to handle them with doing some changes with their keycodes(ASCII values) on LWUIT libraries, and I succeed, but this did not work on back button. I have already checked 'button.getCommand()' and 'form.setBackCommand()' but it didn't help. when I use setBackCommand ,, it seems to do something (it activates the internet connection) but, still does not go back to previous screen

Comment: It sounds like you compiled the LWUIT J2ME code instead of using the proper LWUIT Blackberry port.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure about your comment. Whaat you mean by LWUIT BB port? Did you mean using RIM JDE or something else?